# SQL query with joins and multiple group by

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I have table messages:

[image]

I want to retrun conversation. Conversation is when id_sender and id_recipient and id_ad are the same in rows. But for example:

First row: id_sender = 1 id_recipient = 2 id_ad = 1

Second row id_sender = 2 id_recipient = 1 id_ad = 1

this 2 rows should be group to one conversation, so I create query:

```
SELECT id_ad
     , id_sender
     , u.name
     , id_recipient
     , uu.name
     , subject from ads.messages m
  JOIN ads.advertisements 
 USING (id_ad)
  JOIN ads.users u 
    ON m.id_sender = u.id_user
  JOIN ads.users uu 
    ON m.id_recipient = uu.id_user
 WHERE m.id_recipient = 133 
    OR m.id_sender = 133
 GROUP 
    BY id_ad
     , id_sender
     , subject
     , u.name
     , m.id_recipient
     , uu.name
```

that return:

[image]

This query is correct but I need return one of result on image above, query should return 3 rows

it doesn't matter which one will be return - To retrun I need all of this column and result rows shoud be 3 not 4

Any ideas?

Comment: *it doesn't matter which one will be return* [sic]. It *should* matter!

Comment: Why should it matter? Two combination of the same thing are essentialy the same thing

Comment: A query to return one of two set of results?  That's barmy.

Comment: @sagi Because computers are not good at processing "I don't care, just pick one you like best".

Answer (score 0):

I must edit a little your code but result is again the same as above:

[image]